# Visibility of another layout within same layout not working?

Tags: android, android-relativelayout

I can't see my textview tv_progress_status in grid_progress_layout, only i can see is my progress bar... so i can't show my progress update. If i cut my Textview code and paste it above progress bar, then textview shows and progressbar not showing.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/Rl_imageframe"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_margin="5dp"
android:background="@drawable/imageframe"
android:paddingBottom="5dp" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_header"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_margin="4dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:textSize="10sp" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/iv_cover_page"
    android:layout_width="90dp"
    android:layout_height="120dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/tv_header"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:contentDescription="@string/cover_page" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/iv_delete"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:background="@drawable/close_btn"
    android:contentDescription="@string/cover_page"
    android:visibility="invisible" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/b_footer"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="15dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/iv_cover_page"
    android:layout_margin="4dp"
    android:background="@drawable/issue_selector_red"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:textSize="9sp" />

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/grid_progress_layout"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" >

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar1"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="15dp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:max="100"
        android:progressDrawable="@drawable/progressbarlayout" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_progress_status"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:text="100"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white" />
</RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Try adding android:layout_below="@id/progressBar1" for textview tv_progress_status

Comment: probably because both has  android:layout_centerInParent="true". Try to give relative position to text view in accordance with progress bar.

Comment: I tried both but same result

Answer (score 0):

Change code of two layout,hope its work.

```
<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/progressBar1"
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="15dp"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:max="100"
    android:progressDrawable="@drawable/progressbarlayout" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_progress_status"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
   android:layout_below="@id/progressBar1"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:text="100"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white" />
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

try to change your `RelativeLayout` that contain progress view to `FramLayout` like this :

```
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/grid_progress_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" >

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar1"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="15dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:max="100"
        android:progressDrawable="@drawable/progressbarlayout" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_progress_status"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:text="100"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white" />
</FrameLayout>
```